# Pass tensorrt test but cannot import tensorrt

Tags: tensorrt

I try to install tensorrt7.2.3.4,,and my system is win10, cuda 11.1, python3.8.

After following the installation instructions, I conducted a tensorrt test：
[Tensorrt samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UE8w.png)

We can see that tensorrt should be installed normally

But when I want to import tensorrt，the error appear:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wbYF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead use docker image which "nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:19.10-py3"
Install all the dependencies using pip or pipenv